# Is it possible to combine RSS feeds and other stories in the same view?

Tags: views, entities, feeds

I subscribe to an RSS feed I would like to post in the same view as some user-generated stories and I would like both types of content to display as a uniform list. Can that be easily done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you give more details? Do you mean importing a feed into your website and then displaying its contents alongside your own? You'd need the Feeds module to do that.

UPDATE: Yes, this is possible. You need the Feeds module, and to create a content-type to hold the feeds. When displaying your view, use Filters to narrow it down to just your user-entry content-type and the Feeds-info content-type, and they will both display (in whatever order you set, the default is posted date).

Comment: Yes basically I have a view that I want to populate with an RSS news feed on a daily basis, but I also want my users to be able write stories that would appear in that same view. So the view ends up being a combination of RSS news stories as well as stories submitted by the website's administrators.